# How to implement auth guard for graphql subscriptions (passportjs + cookies)

Tags: cookies, graphql, passport.js, nestjs, graphql-subscriptions

How I can pass user to the request?
Is there any possible way to implement something like SubscriptionAuthGuard?

**without the subscription, everything works fine**

Code:

```js
GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      installSubscriptionHandlers: true,
      subscriptions: {
        'subscriptions-transport-ws': {
          onConnect: (connectionParams, webSocket) =>
            new Promise((resolve) => {
              passportInit(webSocket.upgradeReq, {} as any, () => {
                resolve(webSocket.upgradeReq);
              });
            }),
        },
      },
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    }),
```

Error:

```sh
TypeError: Cannot set property 'authInfo' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, I'm using JWT and bearer tokens.

GraphQL.module:

```
    'subscriptions-transport-ws': {
      path: '/graphql',
      onConnect: (connectionParams) => {
        return {
          req: {
            headers: { authorization:
                connectionParams.Authorization ??
                connectionParams.authorization,
            },
          },
        };
      },
    },
```

Guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      return (await super.canActivate(context)) as boolean;
    } catch (e) {
      throw new AuthenticationError(generalErrorMessages.invalidToken);
    }
  }

  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext): Request {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);

    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution works for me. Make sure to use correct field number because it is case-sensitive

Comment: @farizmamad indeed, I've updated my example to check for either, since lower case i believe is more common